# regex return false?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
console.log(rule);
// rule = max18
// rule = max120
// rule = max6
var pattMax = new RegExp('^(max).(\d{1,3})');

pattMax.test(rule); //false?

if(pattMax.test(rule)){
    console.log('é max seguido de 1 á 3 digitos');
}
```

Comment: Da pra simplificar essa regex ai, sempre deve casar `max1`, `max12` ou `max123`? vai utilizar os grupos p alguma coisa?

Comment: não, como ficaria? mas nesse não esta passando e quando testo em sites como regexr funciona.

Comment: Em teoria, basta `^max\d{1,3}` - o ponto pegaria outros caracteres, como max_121. Max120 funcionaria pelo motivo errado, o ponto pegaria o 1, e o /d{1,3} pegaria o 20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estavas quase lá. Tens de escapar `\d` para `\\d` dentro do construtor da RegExp. Senão ele é "esquecido". Repara aqui como a barra desaparece:

```js
console.log(new RegExp('^(max).(\d{1,3})'));
```

Se fizesses a regex assim `var pattMax = /'^(max).(\d{1,3})/;` o teu código quase ia funcionar:

```js
var pattMax = /^(max).(\d{1,3})/;
['max18', 'max120', 'max6'].forEach(function(rule) {
    console.log(pattMax.test(rule) ? 'é max seguido de 1 á 3 digitos' : 'Falhou!');
});
```

O que falha é que ele espera `max` mais um caracter qualquer excepto nova linha (o `.`) e depois numeros na quantidade de 1 a 3, ora aí falha.

Acho que podias usar somente assim: `/^max\d{1,3}/` sem construtor:

```js
var pattMax = /^max\d{1,3}/;
['max18', 'max120', 'max6'].forEach(function(rule) {
    console.log(pattMax.test(rule) ? 'é max seguido de 1 á 3 digitos' : 'Falhou!');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Você precisa escapar o `\d` ou passar o argumento `i` no construtor da regex.

```
var pattMax = new RegExp('^(max)(\d{1,3})', 'i');

pattMax.test(rule); //false?

if(pattMax.test(rule)){
    console.log('é max seguido de 1 á 3 digitos');
}
```

Baseado em: [javascript new regexp from string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5172183/1342547)

Answer (score 5):

Em teoria, basta `^max\d{1,3}`

O ponto na sua RegEx original pega outros caracteres, como max_121.

Max120 funcionaria pelo motivo errado, o ponto pegaria o 1, e o `/d{1,3}` pegaria o 20.

Descrevendo sua *query*:

```
^(max).(\d{1,3})
^                 marca decomeço da linha
 (   ) (       )  grupos de retorno
  max             literal "max"
      .           qualquer caractere, mas tem que ter algum
        \d{1,3}   de um a três dígitos
```

Versão proposta

```
^max\d{1,3}
^                 começo da linha
 max              literal "max"
    \d{1,3}       de um a três digitos
```

dependendo do uso, pode omitir o `^` (começo da linha), ou mesmo acrescentar `$` no final (fim da linha) caso vá operar em strings maiores e não queira aceitar substrings.